# Is there any alternative to UIElementCollection.Move(oldIndex, newIndex) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, uielement, uielementcollection

I need to re order the children of the panel, I could find Move(oldindex, newindex) in UWP, but not in WPF. Is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

I know it can be done by removing and inserting. But in my case, I have the possibility for more number of children in the same panel hence it will result in arrange override on each operation. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Move` method on the `UIElementCollection` in WPF but you may move your elements manually inside a `using (Dispatcher.DisableProcessing()){ ... }` statement to disable dispatcher processing while you modify the collection.